# Spark DataFrame transformation - remove words of less than 3 letters

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am using `RegexTokenizer` and `StopWordsRemover` to `tokenize` my data set for *model building*. In the same time I want to remove words of less than 3 letters. Also `http` and `https`. How can I do that? Here is my code:
`

```
val trainDF = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url, table, prop)

 // Tokenize
 val tokenizer = new RegexTokenizer()
    .setGaps(false)
    .setPattern("\\p{L}+")
    .setInputCol("posttext")
    .setOutputCol("words")
 val tokenizedDF = tokenizer.transform(trainDF)

 val filterer = new StopWordsRemover()
  .setCaseSensitive(false)
  .setInputCol("words")
  .setOutputCol("tokens")

 val filteredDF = filterer.transform(tokenizedDF)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Found setMinTokenLength(3) in RegexTokenizer